# Differentiation of an integral with respect to time variable

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a little doubt about an integral that I try to differentiate according to time  $t$. I have tried to do it with Leibniz rule but it did not work.

Here it is ;

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}u\left(c\left(t\right)\right) \exp\left\{ -\int_{0}^{t}\theta\left(c\left(s\right)ds\right)\right\} dt$$

$u(c(s))$ is an utility function in terms of consumption $c(s)$

Comment: The integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}u\left(c\left(t\right)\right)exp\left\{ -\int_{0}^{t}\theta\left(c\left(s\right)ds\right)\right\} dt$$ is a number, not a function of $t$, hence differentiating it with respect to $t$ has no sense and would yield zero.

Comment: No, $u$ is a function of $c(t)$ which means that $u$ is a function of time.

Comment: What exactly do you want to differentiate? (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: As I have a function $u$ in terms of consumption $c(t)$ where t is the time, I try to differenciate all this term according to time. I hope it was more clear. Thank you so much.
@Did

Comment: Still unclear--please refer to my first comment.

Comment: Maybe this analogy will help: how would you differentiate $\int_0^1 t^2 \,dt$ with respect to $t$? Since $t$ is being integrated over, it is not present in the value of the integral. The value is $1/3$. (So, if you insist on differentiating it somehow, the derivative is $0$.)

Comment: This differentiation exists in a paper of an economist (Intertemporal Independence, impatience and dynamics of Maurice Obstfeld. Paper published in Journal of Monetary Economics in 1990) and he takes the derivative of this expression according to time and he finds the derivative which is equals to $u(c)-\theta(c)U$ where big U is equal to 


$$\int_{0}^{\infty}u\left(c\left(t\right)\right) \exp\left\{ -\int_{0}^{t}\theta\left(c\left(s\right)ds\right)\right\} dt$$

@CareBear

Comment: The author takes the derivative with respect to $c(t)$. This is called the *Volterra derivative* in the paper, also known as [First variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation).

Comment: In any event, you should update the question with the reference (preferably link) to the paper and page number where this computation appears.

Comment: I am so new at mathstackexchange. Thank you very much for all informations @CareBear